# Possible ways to select consecutive values of columns in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have created a table with 6 columns and 17 rows, What I wanted to do is, I am making a C# .NET project, in the Form, I have placed 102 (6*17) labels, and I want to set the text of each label by getting the values from the table.

So, my question is how to get values, say, 1st or 2nd or 3rd one of the 1st column from my table and then Second column and so on?

```
SqlConnection marksheetsConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HIMANSHU-PC;Initial Catalog=marksheets;Integrated Security=True");
        marksheetsConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand subjectCode11 = new SqlCommand("I DON'T KNOW THE QUERY", marksheetsConnection);
        SqlDataReader subjectCode11Reader = subjectCode11.ExecuteReader();
        string subjectCode1 = subjectCode11Reader.GetString(0);

        label1.Text= subjectCode1;
```

Comment: That sounds like a bad choice. What are you actually trying to do? Maybe there is a better solution for that task.

Comment: As long as you don't tell us the definition of your sql table, we can't really help you much.

Comment: I am making a sort of a Result Card, the background image of my Form is the photograph of the actual result card (with marks erased).
Now I have to fill those spaces with the marks I have stored in the database.
The database has the following columns: (SubjectCode,Subject,Type,MarksObtd,MinPassMarks,MaxMarks) which has 17 rows. For each cell, I want to display its value in a label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        SqlConnection marksheetsConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HIMANSHU-PC;Initial Catalog=marksheets;Integrated Security=True");
        marksheetsConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand subjectCode11 = new SqlCommand("Select SubjectCode,Subject,Type,MarksObtd,MinPassMarks,MaxMarks from Semester1", marksheetsConnection);
        SqlDataReader subjectCode11Reader = subjectCode11.ExecuteReader();
        while (subjectCode11Reader.Read())
        {
            string subjectCode1 = subjectCode11Reader.GetString(0);
            label1.Text = subjectCode1;
        }
```

Comment: ohkay! Let me be more clear, 

    This is my table: http://i42.tinypic.com/141g6p.jpg
    This is my form background: http://i43.tinypic.com/10z4baa.jpg

I have placed labels on the form at each cell, and I want to set the text of the label to the corresponding value of the cell from the database!

Comment: So, all 17 rows at the same time and no new rows! No student_id. I am making it for just 1 student (me). Also, no other tables!

Comment: your query should be something like this.
SqlCommand subjectCode11 = new SqlCommand("Select SubjectCode,Subject,Type,MarksObtd,MinPassMarks,MaxMarks from Semester1", marksheetsConnection);

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. There is an example at the bottom of the page that shows how to read from a SQL database and read each row iteratively.